# Deploy WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I'm using InstallShield with MS Visual Studio 2012 to deploy my WPF application.

In the solution of my application, there are some projects that use .Net Framework 4.0 and some other projects that use .Net Framework 4.5.

My application is using Telerik RadControl.

After deploying my application and installing on client machine (the client machine was installed .Net Framework 4.5 full package), When run my app on this client machine, it will be crashed with message `"My App has stopped working"`, the detail message of problem is below

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: myapp.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 52149029
  Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929
  Problem Signature 06: 4ffa7956
  Problem Signature 07: 7fc6
  Problem Signature 08: ee
  Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.49
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
```

Someone please show me how to solve this problem?

Many Thanks,

T&T

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. It caused by missing some environment dll, and it work fine after installing Visual C++ Redistributable http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679.